# Python get env from finished subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, environment-variables, subprocess

python3.9

So I have a subprocess like so

```
m_env = os.environ.copy()

process = subprocess.Popen(
    ['export', 'TEST=test'],
    env=m_env,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    shell=True
)
result = process.wait()

new_env = process.getenv() #how to get this so the new_env has the 'TEST=test' in it.
```

Now the subprocess itself is modifying the env, and i wanna know how can i get this modified env from the process, the example is using export, however i run a script which may change or add other env variables, so i'd like to get the whole env.

Comment: You'll need to get it before the process ends, because the environment disappears with the process.

Comment: Any changes made to its environment while it is running amounts to private state, so it's not clear why this is of any more interest than any other variables it maintains during its run.

Comment: Also, note that `['export', 'TEST=test'], shell=True` runs `sh -c 'export' 'TEST=test'`, which doesn't pass any arguments to `export` at all, so even if you _could_ retrieve the final environment, `TEST` would not be part of it.

Comment: good point, so far i dont think i can get the env once the process ends. which means ill have to figure out some way to get the out put of the script and then env in one go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution posted by @Pavel Hamerník was the starting point. With the guidance of comment discussions from @Charles Duffy, the following solution is what works best for my implementation.

```
import os
import subprocess

def main():
    m_env = os.environ.copy()
    process = subprocess.Popen(
        ['/bin/bash', '-c', '. /path/script.sh && export > /tmp/env.txt'],
        env=m_env,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        shell=True
    )
    process.wait()
    print(process.stdout.read()) # read the stdout from script


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Note: the export output is being directed to a file in `/tmp/`.

Comment: Using `shell=True` is very silly here -- you're running `sh -c '/bin/bash /path/to/script && export >/tmp/env.txt'`. Why start _two_ shells, `sh` and `bash`, when you only need one?

Comment: Also, `/bin/bash /path/to/script.sh` waits for the copy of bash to exit before it runs `export`; consequently, `export` can't see environment changes made by `script.sh`, because the copy of bash executing that script has exported before it's run.

Comment: What you probably _want_ is `subprocess.Popen(['bash', '-c', '. /path/to/script.sh && export >/tmp/env.txt'])`, which _sources_ the script instead of running it as a subprocess, so the copy of `export` is run in the same interpreter that ran `script.sh`. There are caveats -- if the script calls `exit`, `export` won't run -- but that's innate to the business; once a program exits its environment variables are lost no matter what.

Comment: Valid point about `shell=True`, during my messing around, i just forgot to remove it.

as for environment visibility, you are correct, i noticed that during testing, and fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You can print all the environment variables in the subprocess shell, but you have to parse the data afterwards.

```py
import os
import subprocess

def main():
    m_env = os.environ.copy()
    process = subprocess.Popen(
        ['export TEST=test && export'],
        env=m_env,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        shell=True
    )
    process.wait()
    print(process.stdout.read()) # all environment variables


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Edit: Changed environment printing function from `printenv` (which can be ambiguous when parsing) to `export`. Thanks to [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy)

Comment: I do not suggest trying to parse output from `printenv`. Its output doesn't let you distinguish one variable assigned with `export FOO=$'bar\nBAZ=qux'` and two variables, `export FOO=bar` and `export BAZ=qux`.

Comment: Easier-to-unambiguously-parse might be the output from `export TEST=test && cat /proc/self/environ` (which works because `cat` is a separate process rather than a shell builtin, so its environment at startup time includes `TEST`)

Comment: Ok what about `['export TEST=test && export']` then. It outputs data like this when decoded from binary output
`export TEST='test'\nexport WSLENV=''\nexport WSL_DISTRO_NAME='Ubuntu-20.04'\n`

Comment: If you have a bash-compatible parser, maybe, but I'd still argue that the NUL-delimited form in `/proc/self/environ` is easier -- just split it on NULs and you're done, as nothing is escaped at all (and nothing _needs to be_ escaped, because environment variables cannot contain NULs).

Comment: Also, the output of `export` is subject to change based on which shell provides `/bin/sh`, so even if it behaves one way on one machine doesn't mean it'll behave the same way on a different one. Sure, procfs is Linux-specific, but within Linux it's very consistent.

Comment: This partially works, but its still hard to distinguish the output from a script (the export was an example) and the env vars.

if the args are '/bin/bash /path/script.sh && export', its difficult to tell the difference between scripts output, and the export.

Comment: @Anu, there's no fixing that unless you do the work to provide a separate output channel (f/e, pass a filename or a pre-opened file descriptor for the content to be written to). For arbitrary streamed content, stdout and stderr are what you've got available.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I agree, maybe i can have the process write the env to a file and then read back that file.

Comment: This may do the trick for me 
'/bin/bash /path/script.sh && export > /tmp/env.txt'

stdout get the output from the script, and the export goes to the env.txt file.

Comment: @Anu, note that using fixed (or even predictable) filenames in `/tmp` opens you up to some classes of security problems. You might start with https://lwn.net/Articles/390323/ for background.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the heads up. Since the args are going to be built in python, the output file and its directory will be places in a restricted directory that only the application has write access to. (this application, and the scripts it  executes using popen have their own user, and very limited perms)